# Getting children of an objects connected through link objects in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf

I'm trying to figure out a SPARQL query for getting all children of an object in a system based on a rdf store where links between objects might have properties, and therefore designed that every link is a separate object and is connected with corresponding objects by "parent" and "child" predicates like so ([illustration link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw5kY.png)) :

```
@prefix o: <http://helloworld.org/object#> .
@prefix r: <http://helloworld.org/relation#> .
@prefix l: <http://helloworld.org/link#> .

l:link1-11
    r:parent o:object1 ;
    r:child o:object11 .
l:link1-12 
    r:parent o:object1 ;
    r:child o:object12 .
l:link12-121
    r:parent o:object12 ;
    r:child o:object121 .
```

I'm relatively new to graph DBs so i'm not sure if such recursive query is possible with current links design (i've come up only with a finite-depth query with many unions). Is it possible to make such a query or should i somehow redo the design?

Comment: `prefix o: <http://helloworld.org/object#> 
prefix r: <http://helloworld.org/relation#> 
prefix l: <http://helloworld.org/link#> 

select ?child {
BIND(o:object1 as ?start)
?start (^r:parent/r:child)+ ?child 
}`

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I should definetly read more about sparql possibilites. Can you please post it as an answer in order for me to accept it or should i do it myself?

Comment: if it works, feel free to post it as your own answer. I'm more than happy with this. You can even accept your own answer then and mark it as completed. Regarding SPARQL language, the query makes use of so-called *property paths* which allows for some kind of traversal. But I agree, if not seen before, rather hard to read and understand.

Comment: just as a small hint. Quite recently, RDF Star has been introduced and pushed forward, it will most likely become an accepted extension of RDF which allows to make statements about statements. This is indeed possible in native RDF already by reification, but rather verbose. With RDF Star you can use a full RDF triple and embed it in subject or object position of another triple. So, you could have `o:object12 r:parentOf o:object121 .` and then make statements about this triple via `<< o:object12 r:parentOf o:object121 >> :someFeature :someValue .` - for me more natural and close to PGs